# haskell error: map is applied to too many arguments

Tags: haskell, dictionary, fold

i keep getting this error and i cant work out why

```
sumSquares a = map (^2) a . foldr (+) 0
```

Im adding up the squares of a list of numbers.

Comment: it looks like you used (.) in wrong order. sumSquares = foldr (+) 0 . map (^2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` is function composition, so what you're saying is, take the function `foldr (+) 0 :: [Int] -> Int` and compose it with `map (^2) a :: [Int]`, but this makes no sense, your second "function" in this composition isn't really a function.

Would you'd want instead is to swap them and use application, not composition

```
 foldr (+) 0 (map (^2) a)
 foldr (+) 0 $ map (^2) a
```

and this can be converted back into composition with what's called "eta conversion"

```
 sumSquares = foldr (+) 0 . map (^2)
 sumSquares = sum . map (^2)
```

As an aside, `foldr` is probably the wrong fold here, `foldl'` would be more space efficient.

Comment: `sum` is also non-struct in its accumulator.

Comment: @TomEllis Yeah, which is why you can blow the stack with it, where as `foldl'` runs in constant space

Answer (score 3):

You want to actually do this:

```
sumSquares a = foldr (+) 0 $ map (^2) a
```

Demo in ghci:

```
ghci> sumSquares [2,2]
8
```

To solve this problem using `(.)` operator, you can use the solution as mentioned by @Sassa:

```
sumSquares = foldr (+) 0 . map (^2)
```

But I find that hard to read, or you can see the jozefg solution where he uses `sum` and `(.)`

Comment: I have been told to use the . operator, why does this not work or how can I alter my code to use the dot? thanks

Comment: @user3105607 See jozefg answer. :)